# Can't get any learning on a simple regression problem with Keras

Tags: regression, keras

I know this problem would be better suited to a simpler technique, but it's a an exercise rather than a real problem. I have generated linspace values for training data and a function across them for labels. I have a simple network and training routine using tf.GradientTape. My code is adapted from the Tensorflow documentation examples (although the example was for a classification problem). The code as copied verbatim from the documentation works as expected for the classification problem they were solving, but my attempt to adapt it to a simple regression problem has failed.

My training data and labels are generated as shown:

```
data = np.linspace(0, 5, 10000)
data = data.reshape(10000, 1)
f = lambda x: 0.5 * (1 + -np.cos(0.7*x))
labels = f(data)
```

My model is created as shown:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = (None, 1)),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='sigmoid'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'),
])
```

The training routine is shown below, I have included my simple batching class but I have tried feeding all of the data at once, as well as as single datums and as several batch sizes, same result every time

```
from IPython.display import clear_output

# optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)
loss_object = tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError()

loss_history = []

class Batcher:
    def __init__(self, data, batch_size):
        self.i = 0
        self.data = data
        self.bs = batch_size
        self.length = len(data)
    
    def next(self):
        if self.i >= self.length - self.bs:
            self.i = 0
        return self.data[self.i:self.i+self.bs]

def train_step(data, labels):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        predictions = model(data, training = True)
        loss_value = loss_object(labels, predictions)
    
    loss_history.append(loss_value.numpy().mean())
    grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))

def train(epochs, batch_size = 32):
    data_batcher = Batcher(data, batch_size)
    label_batcher = Batcher(labels, batch_size)
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        for g in range(int(len(data_batcher.data) / batch_size)):
            x_train = data_batcher.next()
            y_train = label_batcher.next()
            train_step(x_train, y_train)
        clear_output(wait=True)
        print(f"Epoch {epoch}/{epochs} done, Loss: {loss_history[-1]}")
```

As you can see I am using the Adam optimizer with a small learning rate.

I have tried various combinations of activation functions (sigmoid, relu and tanh) for input, hidden and output as well as various learning rates.
I have tried various network shapes, from single hidden with 16 units to a 4-layer deep network.
I have tried including a normalization layer after the input.

No matter what, the loss quickly falls small enough that it's expressed in exponential notation, as low as e^-7, yet the predictions are a straight line parallel to the x-axis (network outputs a constant value regardless of input), not even slightly resembling the data I trained on. (With all tanh I did get a more interesting prediction, but still not particularly close to the label data)

I have tried normalizing the data (although it shouldn't need this, the range of the data is 0-1) using scikit standard scaler, but this led to the loss not changing at all from initial value of about 1.5

My questions are

1. Why does the loss fall to almost 0 (when data is not normalized), yet there is no visible change in the predictions between a randomly initiated and untrained model, and the model after 1000 epochs.
2. What is preventing this model from learning anything at all on what should be a trivially easy problem

Thanks very much for any help